# getting NAs introduced by coercionWarning from changing datatype from char to numeric in R?

Tags: r, list

let me explain,

I have a list which contains different dataframes and for analysis I need to correct the datatype of each dataframe, the data frames has all data stored in it as character, so I want to fix that. but instead of doing this for every single dataframe I thought to use a loop.

so first I remove the columns which I do not want to change to numeric and then I mutate them to numeric. Then I add the columns back and the year was in YYYY-YY format, as a character so I change it to a date and then to a numeric year.

```
library("tidyverse")
temp_num_func <- function(x){
  as.numeric(x, digits = 4) 
}

for(i in 1:length(listofdf)){
  temp_df <- listofdf[[i]]  
  temp_df1 <- select(temp_df, -state_ut, -`_year`) #removed as all 
 #other columns are to be converted into numeric
  temp_df1 <- temp_df1 %>% mutate_if(is.character, temp_num_func)  
  temp_df2 <- select(temp_df, state_ut, `_year`) 
  temp_df2$`_year` <- as.Date(temp_df2$`_year`, format = "%Y") 
  temp_df2$`_year` <- as.numeric(format(temp_df2$`_year`, "%Y")) 
  listofdf[[i]] <- temp_df2 %>% add_column(temp_df1)
}
```

getting error:

> Warning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercion

`dput(head(temp_df1[1:4]))`

output:

> structure(list(primary_only = c("88.68", "91.21", "96.95", "89.74",
> "100", "100"), primary_with_u_primary = c("95.98", "96.92", "99.03",
> "97.37", "100", "100"), primary_with_u_primary_sec_hrsec = c("98.81","99.48", "99.72", "100", "100", "100"), u_primary_only c("91.39","91.39", "96.32", "0", "100", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = #"data.frame")

`dput(head(listofdf[[1]][1:4]))`

> structure(list(state_ut = c("Andaman & Nicobar Islands", "Andaman & Nicobar Islands", "Andaman & Nicobar Islands", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh"), `_year` = c("2013-14", "2014-15", "2015-16", "2013-14", "2014-15", "2015-16"), primary_only = c("98.17", "99.55", "100", "86.89", "91.85", "93.89"), primary_with_u_primary = c("98.68", "98.77", "100", "94.53", "96.07","97.02")), row.names = c(NA,6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please post the output of `dput(head(temp_df1[1:4]))` in the question. (Or of `dput(head(listofdf[[1]][1:4]))`)

Comment: You've got an extra `}` on the mutate_if line

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem of changing datatype of the data frames present in the list of data frames.

```
listofdf <- type.convert(listofdf, as.is = TRUE)

for(i in 1:length(listofdf)){
 listofdf[[i]]$`_year` <- as.Date(listofdf[[i]]$`_year`, format = "%Y") 
 listofdf[[i]]$`_year` <- as.numeric(format(listofdf[[i]]$`_year`, "%Y"))
}
```

**All the code in Question is dead weight.**